# Как инициализировать разные переменные в цикле for?

Tags: c++, циклы, for, инициализация

Мне нужно инициализировать две переменные, а точнее одну инициализировать, а в другую наследовать.

`i` - это `int`

`AI` - это `ADDRINFO`

сейчас это не работает

```
for (int i = 0, AI = AddrInfo; AI != NULL;)
```

Если более понятно AI становиться int

пробовал так тоже не работает

```
for (int i = 0, ADDRINFO AI = AddrInfo; AI != NULL;)
```

Инициализировать переменную `int i` заранее, мне нельзя. Иначе придется использовать каждый раз уникальную переменную для каждого цикла for в многопоточности.

Comment: можете подсказать что значит "а в другую наследовать. "?... Как наследуют в переменную?...

Comment: *"Инициализировать переменную int i заранее, мне нельзя. Иначе придется использовать каждый раз уникальную переменную для каждого цикла for в многопоточности."* - это крайне подозрительная фраза. Единственное, чем инициализация переменных инициализации внутри `for` отличается от инициализации заранее - это область видимости, ограниченная внутренностями цикла. Никакой разницы в контексте многопоточности тут не будет и какого именно результаты вы ожидаете - непонятно. Пихать даже одну инициализацию внутрь `for` и вообще несколько несвязанных действий в одну строку является сомнительной затеей.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for(struct { int i; ADDRINFO * AI; } x = {0, AddrInfo }; x.AI != nullptr; )
{
    ...
}
```

Например, так.

Или

```
for(auto [i,AI] = make_tuple(0, AddrInfo); ;)
{
}
```

Comment: Вторая запись из 17го вроде, но я все время забываю как она называется. Но позволяет эксплуатировать утверждение что первое выражение является либо одним простым определением, либо выражением.

Comment: `for(auto [i,AI] = make_tuple(0, AddrInfo); AI != NULL;)`
это кажется подходит, сейчас проверю

Comment: @zip а чем первый не подходит? Оно работает везде

Comment: Не знаю, там ошибка в AddrInfo  и в x, да и он какой то сложный

Comment: ADDRINFO это
`ADDRINFO Hints, * AddrInfo, * AI;`

Comment: @zip О! Гарри точку с запятой забыл после AI

Comment: второй вариант работает отлично спс

Comment: Только я пока не понял как работает make_tuple

Comment: @Swift Таки забыл... Ну и, подправил на предмет уточнений ТС о типах.

Comment: @zip https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding